# best way to Queue render different project files

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, scripting, eevee-render-engine

So I've personally been dealing with rendering bunch of projects.
opening projects, render, then wait until finish. then start another render and repeat takes too much time.

So I've been using this code and launching it as **.bat**

(i'm super blind in coding / scripting, i just copy pasted this code from internet)

example:

[image]

it all works well, until today i found one thing that makes this trick useless.
I'm using eevee with indirect lighting. Because indirect lighting stores the cache in memory, and not externaly. so all the reflection cube and indirect lighting is not calculated when i'm rendering with this **.bat** trick.
.
I'm looking for a better way to manage rendering batch of projects. and if i can see progress bar and calculate total time needed its a bonus.
.
I've heard of flamenco render manager, it seems super complicated.... is that the only way ?

Comment: Flamenco v3 is considerably simpler than its predecessor. https://flamenco.blender.org/